# How to cleanup disk space used by restore point

Tags: windows-8.1

I  am running Windows 8.1.
How can i remove/clean up the disk space used by windows restore point? I am running out of disk space, I want to reclaim some by removing restore point disk space.

Thank you fo r any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- right click My Computer, select Properties
- click System Protection on the left side
- click the Configure button
- delete or adjust settings as necessary